# NuGet.Config file is not read for VS2015?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget

As far I've been able to figure out taking a look on [docs.nuget.org](https://docs.nuget.org/ndocs/consume-packages/configuring-nuget-behavior), in order to be able to set my custom nuget repositories I need to set a `NuGet.Config` in whichever of these places:

- `%APPDATA%\NuGet\Nuget.config`
- Solution folder
- Project folder

So, I've created a `NuGet.Config` file with this content in my Project folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageRestore>
    <add key="enabled" value="True" />
    <add key="automatic" value="True" />
  </packageRestore>
  <activePackageSource>
    <add key="Living" value="C:\NugetRepository" />
  </activePackageSource>
</configuration>
```

However, when I look at NuGet package sources list, my `Living` source doesn't appear.

Any ideas?

Comment: I *think* that NuGet.exe will find what you've done but Visual Studio has its own settings that you can find under Tools->Options->NuGet package manager->Package sources. I have had all manner of fun with this but the one added in VS will then be remembered for everything but when I check the code into VSTS, the build process can be pointed to the config file.

Comment: Are you sure, is there no way to set up an custom package source on VS? Otherwise, how could I set a package up on my project?

Comment: You can set up a custom package source using Visual Studio in the place I told you. You can add login credentials and stuff.

Comment: Your NuGet.Config is incorrect. Your package source is not defined in the packageSources section. See Wendy's example in the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

The NuGet package sources list in Visual Studio is read the config from Global NuGet.config under %APPDATA%\NuGet\Nuget.config. So if you want your Living source list in the NuGet Package Source list, please add your Package Source config in Global NuGet.config as below. Then please **restart** your Visual Studio.

```
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="Living" value="C:\NugetRepository" />
  </packageSources>
  <packageRestore>
    <add key="enabled" value="True" />
    <add key="automatic" value="True" />
  </packageRestore>
  <activePackageSource>
    <add key="Living" value="C:\NugetRepository" />
  </activePackageSource>
</configuration>
```